# Changing a product link to go directly to it's product details page - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woothemes

On my woocommerce shop i have products listed which have 2 available links to click through the the product details page, these are on the image itself and on the text below the item which reads 'Select Options'.

The problem i have is that the text below the item seems to open an a side basket window before going the the product page which i want to stop from happening.

You can see the I mean here http://www.konez.co.uk

Anyone know how i can change these links so that they go directly to the product details page without opening that side basket?

Ive been using the Mr. Tailor theme by Get Bowtied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue. Clicking the "select option" link take me to the detail page directly, without animating/changing anything in the DOM.

If the issue is still here, it's probably JS that trigger on click on this link to open some variation selector.

You could fix this by putting a  wrapping all the product content instead of 2 seperated . A proper z-index would put this "empty a" on top of everything, and make the entire area clickable as a simple href.

Comment: I think the theme devs have just fixed it with an update.